# How can I search a nested dictionary with specific constraints in mind

Tags: python, search, dictionary

Hoping someone can suggest an easy way to search a big nested dictionary in a very specific way.

Example of the dict:

```
foo = {"item1" : ((0.1, 0.03 , 0.7), (0.01, 0.01, 0.02), (0.3, 0.4, 0.05)), "item2" : ((0.5, 0.2 , 0.01), (0.1, 0.3, 1.0), (0.4, 0.2, 0.8))}
```

I want to search the above using two constraints. The position of the tuple and a range to search in and return any matching results with their index position in the list and their corresponding dict key, where the key value is a list of true index positions.

example: search position 2 of the tuples using a range of (0.7-1.0) and I want a dict back:

```
{"item1" : (0), "item2" : (1, 2)}
```

I am unsure how to run the search using constraints and format back the results the way I want it. Any suggestions would be great? Many thanks.

Comment: Show us some code for your intended approach.

Comment: Hi Marcin (thanks for cleaning up my post). I've no approach yet, I'm trying to work out how to even go about it. I was looking at for example: filter(lambda number: <filter>, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) but it's the application i'm having issue with. I may need to rethink my Dic to make it easier if it complicates things for the search.

Comment: I have to say, I've found your description of what you want to do pretty opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own function:

```
def special_search(my_dict, pos, min, max):
    result = {}
    for item, tuples in my_dict.items():
        matches = []
        for i, t in enumerate(tuples):
            if min <= t[pos] <= max:
                matches.append(i)
        if matches:
            result[item] = tuple(matches)
    return result
```

Using your example:

```
>>> foo = {"item1": ((0.1, 0.03 , 0.7), (0.01, 0.01, 0.02), (0.3, 0.4, 0.05)),
...        "item2": ((0.5, 0.2 , 0.01), (0.1, 0.3, 1.0), (0.4, 0.2, 0.8))}
>>> special_search(foo, 2, 0.7, 1.0)
{'item2': (1, 2), 'item1': (0,)}
```

Comment: Hi Julio! Thanks, very helpful. I'm fairly new to python and this version I can read the easiest ...thanks all for the suggestions. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize your test using a function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

test = lambda t: 0.7 <= itemgetter(2)(t) <= 1.0
results = dict((k, tuple(n for n,v in enumerate(t) if test(v))) for k,t in foo.items())

print(results)
# {'item2': (1, 2), 'item1': (0,)}
```

Comment: I like the single list comprehension better than the other stuff, I had `dict( (key,tuple(index for index,smalltup in enumerate(bigtup) if my_range[0] <= smalltup[my_index] <= my_range[1])) for key,bigtup in foo.items() )` but the test function is nice

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and faster implementation of julio.alegria's (+1) algorithm:

```
def search(d, pos, min, max):
    searchspace = set(range(min(max))
    answer = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        answer[k] = tuple([i for i,tuple in enumerate(v) if tuple[pos] in searchspace])
    return dict(( (k, d[k]) for k in in d if d[k]))
```